# Ljava/time/ZoneId Crash for Android

Tags: java, android, time

I ran the date code below in my application, but there are crashes on an android 6.0 LGE device. How can I solve the problem? Why does the problem occur?

Regards

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/ZoneId;

Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.time.ZoneId" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.test.trast.oppolar-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.test.trast.oppolar-1/split_config.ar.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.test.trast.oppolar-1/split_config.tr.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.test.trast.oppolar-1/split_config.xxxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.test.trast.oppolar-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

My Code:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of(String.valueOf(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(currentDateandTime);
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ld.atStartOfDay(z);
Instant instantStart = zdtStart.toInstant();
long start = instantStart.getEpochSecond() * 1000;

LocalDate nextDay = ld.plusDays(1);
ZonedDateTime zdtEnd = nextDay.atStartOfDay(z);
Instant instantEnd = zdtEnd.toInstant();
long end = instantEnd.getEpochSecond() * 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using "java.time" package and this package added in api 26.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary

Comment: How can I run this on users lower than sdk 26?

Comment: With quick research, I found this library for using "java.time" with older apis. You can check it out: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Comment: There is [Android API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) now.

Comment: I think I solved my problem with code coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true. Thanks